# Use a plain text editor in RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I am trying to use RefineryCMS as a tool for cataloging web components / widgets examples. As part of this I would like a way to enter plain text into the "Page Parts".  Right now there is a WYSIWYG editor which puts `<br />` and `<p>` tags in my text as I add newlines, even if I switch over to the "HTML" mode.

Is there a plugin to swap out the editor for just a plain textarea that saves the plain text to the database?  If not, how would I go about building that myself? Ideally one Page Part would use the existing HTML editor, and a different Page Part would be able to use the textarea input.

Comment: This is something I would also like to know. I haven't seen anything like this yet, unfortunately.